# Extension to Linear Function: Methodology

Tags: functional-analysis

I am lacking methodology, and hence my solutions are tiresome, for finding extensions to fairly simple linear functions.

The question is this:

> Let $Y$ be the 1-Dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ spanned by $(2,1,1)$. Let $\phi : Y \to \mathbb R$ be defined as $\phi(\lambda(2,1,1)) := \lambda$.
>
> $\mathbb R^3$ and $Y$ have the regular norm.
>
> 1) Find the norm of $\phi$
>
> 2) Find an extension of $\phi$ to $\mathbb R^3$ with the same norm

1) is OK:

> $\sqrt{\lambda^2(2^2 + 1^2 + 1^2)} = \sqrt{6}\lambda = 1 \implies ||\phi||_{op} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$

For 2), I know what the solution is, but not a good way to get there; the solution seems like it shouldn't be too difficult to find, and yet my solution is not short:

> By symmetry in $y,z$ I assume $\phi(x,y,z) = \alpha x + \beta y + \beta z$. We already know $2\alpha + \beta + \beta = \phi(2,1,1) = 1$.
>
> Now we have  $\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} = sup\{\phi(x,y,z): x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1\} = sup\{\alpha x + 2\beta y: x^2 + 2y^2 = 1\}$. Where I have used the symmetry in $y,z$ again. I parametrise this ellipse $(x,y) = (\cos \theta,\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin \theta$), differentiate, and use $2 \beta = 1- 2\alpha$:
>
> $-\alpha \sin \theta + \frac{1-2\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}\cos\theta = 0 \implies \tan\theta = \frac{1 - 2\alpha}{\sqrt{2}}, \alpha x + (1 - 2\alpha) y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \implies \alpha = \frac{1}{3}$, so:
>
> $\phi(x,y,z) = \frac{2x + y + z}{6}$

The same question is asked with the $\ell^1,\ell^\infty$ norms, and it is easier to see solutions "by inspection" (but I wouldn't have come up with these quickly); $\frac{x+y+z}{4}$, and $\frac{x}{2}$. I want to know the tricks to finding such solutions. How would you go about finding these three extensions? Do they look like obvious solutions?

Answer (score 1):

A hint:

Try $\phi({\bf x})=\alpha\>(2,1,1)\cdot{\bf x}$ for a suitable $\alpha\in{\mathbb R}$.

Comment: Ok, so if $\phi(\mathbf x) := \mathbf y . \mathbf x$ for any $\mathbf y$ not a multiple of $\mathbf x$, then this would give a larger norm; in particular $\mathbf y . \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}(2,1,1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}} \implies \mathbf y . \frac{1}{||\mathbf y||}\mathbf y  > \frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}$. Since the norm must be preserved, $\mathbf y = \alpha(2,1,1)$.